# Google gmail on iPad: how do they scroll just the right hand side of the page?

Tags: ipad, browser, scroll, gmail

I am trying to do (EDIT: on a web-app destined primarily for the iPad) what Google does in gmail for iPad:  the left-hand pane containing the list of messages stays put, and the right hand side of the screen (the message content pane) can be scrolled vertically with a touch-gesture.

How is this division of the page with right-side-only scrolling accomplished?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use div scrolling. See [Glovebox](http://blogs.nitobi.com/jesse/2010/05/03/glovebox/) for example. Try this [demo](http://risingj.com/GloveBoxDemo/) on the iPad.

Comment: thanks for this link. It looks as though it leads to interesting and helpful places. If this is the answer, I will come back here and give you credit for the help, which is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After trying to reverse engineer the gmail scrolling and the apple ipad help scrolling, I was directed to http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4.

iscroll-light is great if you only need the smooth scrolling abilities.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`UISplitViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Try this link: [Developing Split View Based Apps for the iPad](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/developing-split-view-based-apps-ipad), or the documentation page linked above.

Comment: thanks for the link -- I may return to it if I decide to learn Objective C which I've only looked at a little. I've edited my original post to make clearer that I'm trying to do this in the browser.

Comment: @Tim: Sounds good. Also, I would include some web-oriented tags in future if you want to attract the right type of answerers since I, for example, know next-to nothing about web-programming.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's in the web browser, I'd guess they're using CSS `position: fixed;`.

Comment: I've read that webkit for Safari iPad does not support fixed-position elements, and so I'm guessing it will have to be more involved than that.

Comment: @Tim Do you have link supporting that?  I'd be interested in knowing if it's the case.

Comment: Or better yet, if you have an iPad, throw together a quick test.

Comment: As a guy who knows what that is and has an iPad to test it on - they're not. They've got two panels, both with one-finger scroll-ability, much like an iPad split pane app. I'm still not clear on how to achieve this effect, because overflow:scroll requires two-finger scrolling...

Comment: @alirobe Please clarify: Are you saying that you've actually created a test case for `position: fixed` and verified that Safari on the iPad doesn't support it?

Comment: position: fixed doesn't work for ipad, as far as my experience goes

Answer (score 0):

@chris I don't think they are, because gmail is a web based app, not a native ipad app. 
I'm not sure if this will help but take a look at this: http://www.domedia.org/oveklykken/css-div-scroll.php

Comment: This should be added as a comment, if you're wanting to do "@someone"

Comment: @Amber 50 rep points are necessary in order to post comments.

Comment: I don't see how this could be a bad answer.

Comment: @George ah, right... it's been a while since that was on my mind. :)

Comment: @Amber It's certainly understandable.  This is the second time I've pointed that out recently. :D

Comment: TBH, I'd think it'd make more sense that adding comments and adding answers should both not have rep requirements, but hey. :)

Comment: I'm afraid overflow:scroll requires two-finger scrolling to actually scroll, which is quite user un-friendly considering the complete lack of a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Use touchstart, touchmove and touchend events. You would also need to prevent the event from bubbling up - preventDefault.